# How to aggregate back a split word in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to aggregate a split word back together. The reason I split the word in the first place because I want to capitalize to all the first letter. For example, `dog corki` would return `Dog Corki` in capital. I have the following code, but the offset function does not help to align all the word back. It returns the following

```
 Corki Dog Golden
 Corki Retriver
```

However, I want it to return the following

```
Corki
Dog Corki
Golden Retreiver
```

Here is the code:

```
WITH array_table AS (
  SELECT "corki" AS dog UNION ALL
  SELECT "dog corki" UNION ALL
  SELECT "golden retriever"
)
,

split_table AS (
SELECT SPLIT(array_table.dog, " ") AS split_word
FROM array_table
)

SELECT 
  -- split_table.split_word,
  -- unnest_split_word,
  -- pos
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTR(unnest_split_word, 1, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTR(unnest_split_word, 2))), ' ')
FROM 
split_table,
UNNEST(split_table.split_word) AS unnest_split_word
WITH OFFSET AS pos
GROUP BY pos
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [INITCAP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#initcap) function instead.

```sql
WITH array_table AS (
  SELECT "corki" AS dog UNION ALL
  SELECT "dog corki" UNION ALL
  SELECT "golden retriever"
)
SELECT INITCAP(dog) FROM array_table;

+------------------+
|       f0_        |
+------------------+
| Corki            |
| Dog Corki        |
| Golden Retriever |
+------------------+
```

And if we use your approch, below will return same result as above.

```sql
WITH array_table AS (
  SELECT "corki" AS dog UNION ALL
  SELECT "dog corki" UNION ALL
  SELECT "golden retriever"
),
split_table AS (
  SELECT FORMAT('%t', t) AS hash_id, *
    FROM array_table t, UNNEST(SPLIT(dog, " ")) AS split_word WITH offset
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(INITCAP(split_word), ' ' ORDER BY offset)
  FROM split_table
 GROUP BY hash_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is so much easier :)

Comment: I also see that another key here is to group by `hash_id` since I was grouping by offset, and that caused to only show 2 rows. Thanks again.